# Declare link list of struct who contains template

Tags: c++, templates

The typedef declaration is not allowed (SAPPLICATION_POOL_HEADER was not declared....)
Why?

```
template <class T>
typedef struct _sApplicationPoolHeader
{
    SAPPLICATION_POOL_LIST sApplicationList;
    T oData;
}SAPPLICATION_POOL_HEADER,
    *PSAPPLICATION_POOL_HEADER;

template <class T>
typedef LinkedListTemplate<SAPPLICATION_POOL_HEADER> LinkList;
```

edit:
The definition of SAPPLICATION_POOL_LIST:

```
typedef struct _sApplicationPoolList
{
    struct _sApplicationPoolList* psPrevApplication;
    struct _sApplicationPoolList* psNextApplication;
}SAPPLICATION_POOL_LIST,
    *PSAPPLICATION_POOL_LIST,
        **PPSAPPLICATION_POOL_LIST;
```

Comment: It seems like some parts are missing from your example, such as the definitions of `SAPPLICATION_POOL_LIST` and `LinkedListTemplate`.

Comment: @DanRoche see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typedef` cannot be templated.  Assuming you have (at least) C++ 11, you can use a *type alias* using the `using` keyword to do this.

```
template <class T>
struct sApplicationPoolHeader
{
    SAPPLICATION_POOL_LIST sApplicationList;
    T oData;
};

template <typename T>
using LinkList = sApplicationPoolHeader<T>;
```

In your original you included names for `SAPPLICATION_POOL_HEADER` and `PSAPPLICATION_POOL_HEADER` as well.  This is generally unnecessary in C++ (this was a common idiom in C, since without a typedef a `struct` needed to be included in the type), but if you want these as well,

```
// Pure alias of SAPPLICATION_POOL_HEADER for sApplicationPoolHeader
template <typename T>
using SAPPLICATION_POOL_HEADER = sApplicationPoolHeader<T>;

// Alias of PSAPPLICATION_POOL_HEADER for pointer to sApplicationPoolHeader
template <typename T>
using PSAPPLCIATION_POOL_HEADER = sApplicationPoolHeader<T> *;
```